# Why Javascript console.log result is NaN when I tried Repeat a string a specified times

Tags: javascript, string, function, nan, invoke

```
function repeatS(srr, num) {
    if (num <= 0) {
        return "";
    }
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result = +srr;
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(repeatS("ahfidhfd", 3));
```

**strong text**

Here is my question, the result is Nan, anyone knows what might be the problem here...

Answer (score 2):

`result = +srr;`

should be

`result += srr;`

Answer (score 1):

You use an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for converting a string to a number, but you need to assign the value to the left hand variable.

```js
function repeatS(srr, num) {
    if (num <= 0) {
        return "";
    }
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += srr;
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(repeatS("ahfidhfd", 3));
```